# jQuery datatables keep pagination on sort

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to configure jquery datatable to stay on current page when sorting table?
To sort I'm using:

```
table.fnSort([columnName, 'dsc']);
```

Comment: you should look at [`localStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: How localStorage can help me in jquery plugin?

Comment: localStorage won't work in older versions or if you are using IE 8 or below. Let me know your jQuery version. And also version of IE (if you want to run your application in IE).

Comment: Otherwise you need to use cookies

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.10.2. How localStrorage or cookies can help with datatables?

Comment: @Toma 1) See 'fnStateSave' in http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks   . I think this is enough for you to save the state of your datatable. 2) In addition to that, if you want to know how to use local storage see:  https://www.datatables.net/blog/2012-01-16      AND generally if your datatable has more data ( more than 4 KB ), then you need to use localstorage. Because cookies cannot store larger data. Thats what I know. Good luck and do some research

Comment: Please add it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
table.order([columnName, 'dsc']).draw(false);
```